# Is it possible to enter text into an excel userform from a commandbutton on the same userform?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to make an excel userform appear to behave more like an independent app than a userform. I would rather program an app but because of company IT rules that is not an option.

See image. Is it possible to enter data into an active textbox on the form by using a commandbutton on the included key pad?

Image of userform:

[image]

The form is not coded yet.

Thanks

Comment: you could assign a variable to them on entry, say `set tb=me.textbox1` and then `tb.value=tb.value & cmdButton9.caption` on cmdButton9's click event.  Creating a custom button through event sinking to, would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what entering numbers using "keypad buttons" on a user form has to do with making it "behave more like an independent app".  As a user, this would drive me completely insane - a 10-key is *way* easier to use than an on-screen keypad.  Why not just restrict the input in the textboxes to numbers?

Comment: The reason for the keypad buttons is this will be on an android tablet. Here is a link to the file as it exists today. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwdj1JR-uqVrR0NxSnpRemNURUk/view?usp=sharing

I am actually looking at two different methods. One totally with a userform and the other with a userform that is only a keypad entering data on "Input" sheet and then transferring those entries via vba to the "Projected" sheet.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you running VBA code on an Android tablet? VBA requires a pretty full suite of COM services that are only available on via the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do. Actually, once you click on the button to enter data on the button, the textbox would not be active any more. Anyhow, if you do not need the activetextbox, but another one, you may use the following code:

Let's say that you have a button `btnOpenFile` and a Label `lblInformation`.
You want, once you click on the button, to get "ALE ALE" in the `lblInformation`.

The most simple code to achieve this is probably this one:

```
Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click()

    me.lblInformation = "ALE ALE"

End Sub
```

Put it inside the UserForm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in support of my comment

```
Private tb As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    tb.Value = tb.Value & CommandButton1.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    tb.Value = tb.Value & CommandButton2.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    tb.Value = tb.Value & CommandButton3.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    tb.Value = tb.Value & CommandButton4.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Set tb = Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    Set tb = Me.TextBox2
End Sub
```